# How to sync photos from Aperture on Mac to Android?

Tags: sync, gallery, macos

My photos are stored in Aperture on my Mac. I would like to sync them so they show in Gallery on my Nexus 7.

Restrictions:

- I want to sync over USB or, preferably, WiFi. Uploading to a cloud server from the computer then pulling them back on the tablet is no use, given the speed of my connection and the number of photos.
- If there's something that syncs to a companion Android app rather than Gallery, that app needs to support Daydream so I can have my photos appear in Photo Table when the tablet is locked.
- Manually exporting the photos from Aperture to a folder is no good — I need something automatic that will export new photos when they appear in the selected projects / smart albums.
- Switching to iPhoto or Lightroom is also not an option :)
- As the photos are mostly 14Mp RAW files, converting to JPG is essential; scaling them down to a smaller size would also be useful.

Is there anything that will do what I want? DoubleTwist doesn't support Aperture yet; Missing Sync is expensive and the trial version refused to pair with my tablet in any case, so I can't see if the Aperture sync is any good with that.